# Find numbers in strings in a dataframe column with various data types

Tags: python, pandas, split

I have a dataframe (df):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['it is 54321', 'it is 54322']})
```

I can find the numbers in it:

```
df['B'] = df['A'].apply(lambda str:[int(s) for s in str.split() if s.isdigit()])
```

But when there are various data types:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [54321, 'it is 54322', 'is it 54323 or 4?', np.NaN]})
```

I get:

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use replace regex.
Must begin by replacing any non alphanumeric `[^\w]':''`

Then replace any non digits at the start of string `'^\D+':''`

Finally replace any non digits in the middle of the string with space `'\D+':' '`

Split the string using space to get it to list

```
df['B']= df.A.replace(regex={'[^\w]':'','^\D+':'','\D+':' '}).str.split('\s')



              A           B
0              54321         NaN
1        it is 54322     [54322]
2  is it 54323 or 4?  [54323, 4]
3                NaN         NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

First thing to note `str` is a Python keyword, avoid using it as a variable.

Now, to solve your problem, you can check if the cell is a string or not with `isinstance`:

```
df['B'] = df['A'].apply(lambda x:[int(s) for s in x.split() if s.isdigit()]
                                 if isinstance(x,str) else x)
```

Output:

```
                   A        B
0              54321    54321
1        it is 54322  [54322]
2  is it 54323 or 4?  [54323]
3                NaN      NaN
```